# Excel or DBMS as data source to Datagridview in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, excel, datagridview

Language: VB.Net
Platform: Windows
IDE: Visual Studio 2013

I have an application in which I use data from 100 Excel sheets loaded through datagridview. The user can modify data through datagridview which is used for calculation. The database is static and datagridview changes does not effect database.

Which is preferable using Excel or some DBMS considering the efficiency of reading and writing (in future versions). In am working in VB.Net.

Thanks for answering, I am new to coding...  :)

Comment: use sql to save and retrieve data via grid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"considering the efficiency of reading and writing"... databases usually win when data size reaches a certain level. And of course there are other benefits to databases that aren't readily available in Excel: type integrity, queries, table relationships, etc.

The one thing that Excel does have going for it is formulas. If you are heavily dependent upon those in your worksheets, that might require some planning before converting to DBs. For example, still using Excel as the UI and enabling the user to work with formulas, but upon saving the resulting data gets uploaded to the database. But that all depends upon the specifics of your project.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve

```
 dim da as new sqldataAdapter("select *from tblname",conn)
 dim ds as new dataset
 da.Fill(ds)
 datagridview1.DataSource=ds.Tables(0)
```

to save

```
 for each r as datagridrow in datagridview1.rows
    for each c as datagridcell in r
        'sql insert code
    next
 next
```